# Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App, BackgroundTask is not running when trigger is set as Pushnotification

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a BackgroundTask for raw push notification and followed below steps. But the BackgroundTaks is not running when trigger is set as PushNotificationTrigger.

1. I have created a Portable Windows Runtime Component Project.
2. Create a class MyTask, here is the complete code of MyTask class

   ```
   namespace WindowsRuntimeComponent1
   {
       public sealed class MyTask : IBackgroundTask  
       {
           public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
           {
               RawNotification rawNotification = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as RawNotification;

           }  
       }
   }
   ```
3. Added reference of Windows Runtime Component project to Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app.
4. Package.appxmanifest has below declaration
   [image]
5. The BackgroundTask registration has below code which executes on click of button.

   ```
   private async void RegisterBackgroundTask(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       var access = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

       if (access != BackgroundAccessStatus.Denied)
       {
           BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
           builder.AddCondition(new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable));
           builder.Name = "PushTaskTest";
           builder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(WindowsRuntimeComponent1.MyTask).FullName;
           builder.SetTrigger(new PushNotificationTrigger());

           builder.Register();
       }
   }
   ```
6. Code to register for PushnotificationChannel

   ```
   protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

       NotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub(
         "testmobileservicehub",
         "Endpoint=sb://testmobileservicehub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=WR6Fstfuc+1PpNspuJlcV3t57UPfXLU=");

       var result = await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri);  
   }
   ```
7. Now when I am running the app, Lifecycle Events is showing "No Background Tasks"

[image]

8. But when I put SystemTrigger, Lifecycle Events showed up.

[image]

Can any one please help why BackgroundTask is not running in case of Push notification trigger?

Comment: I have same issue, have you fixed it?

Comment: Any solution found? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: Note Background tasks using the ControlChannelTrigger or PushNotificationTrigger, and background tasks using a SystemTrigger with the SmsReceived trigger type, cannot be activated in this manner. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/debug-a-background-task